# What is '*' next to branch name means on Mac Iterm2?

Tags: macos, iterm2

like in the title, I can't find what is that '*' next to my branch means..
Terminal is iTerm2 on MacOS.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your repository has 2 stashes.
You can check them by typing `git stash list`